OpenProcess only works via vistual studio execution
I am having issues with my c++ code. When I run it via Visual Studio, it works properly and no issues or errors are being logged. When I try to run a CMD as administrator and run the program, I get an error that's being logged in my code.
This is what I've tried:
int FindSysmainSvc()
{
    SC_HANDLE scm = OpenSCManager(nullptr, nullptr, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
    if (!scm) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open service control manager: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    SC_HANDLE service = OpenService(scm, L"SysMain", SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if (!service) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open service: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        return -1;
    }

    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS status;
    DWORD bytesNeeded;
    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(service, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&status), sizeof(status), &bytesNeeded)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to query service status: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseServiceHandle(service);
        CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD processId = status.dwProcessId;

    CloseServiceHandle(service);
    CloseServiceHandle(scm);

    return processId;
}

int main() {
    int pid = FindSysmainSvc();

    if (pid == -1) {
        std::cout << "[!] Failed to find pid\n";
        return -1;
    }

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);
    if (hProcess == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "[!] OpenProcess(): FAILED";
        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}

The pid is returned successfully on both visual studio execution and CMD one.
I get the "[!] OpenProcess(): FAILED" error in CMD whereas in visual studio execution the process handle gets retrieved successfully.

What error did you get? I expect its important to help figure out what the problem is. What did GetLastError return?

Yes sorry, I modified the question now I forgot to add it

What does GetLastError() return in the failure case?

Please modify this code:  std::cout << "[!] OpenProcess(): FAILED"; to std::cout << "[!] OpenProcess(): FAILED with code: " << GetLastError(); to see what you OS says about the problem.

[!] OpenProcess(): FAILED with code: 5

Probably different in debug privileges. Your exe have it when exec by vs and have not when exec from explorer. In any case you must first enable debug privileges before open process

5 says access is denied: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499- Do you need elevation which is different from just being an administrator?

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1644815/how-does-one-obtain-process-all-access-rights-to-a-running-process

I'm not really sure if I need elevation different from just being an administrator. I configured my executable's execution level to require administrator anyways

After I commented I found that the documentation for PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS says you need SeDebugPrivilege and explains privileges here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/changing-privileges-in-a-token

Check with what privileges the process/service you're trying to open requires. There are processes that you can't even modify or open with "normal" administator or debug rights.

Another unrelated thing to note is that dwProcessId is a DWORD, not an int. There's no reason to not use the proper type.

Very rarely will you ever need PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS. Don't request more than the minimum rights that you actually need to accomplish a task.

I need PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS because I am trying to hook the sysmain process

Holding a privilege is not sufficient. You'll also need to enable it.

dwDesiredAccess:The access to the process object. This access right is checked against the security descriptor for the process. If the caller has enabled the SeDebugPrivilege privilege, the requested access is granted regardless of the contents of the security descriptor.
According to the Doc:Process Security and Access Rights

To open a handle to another process and obtain full access rights, you
must enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege.

Even if you have permission, it won't be enabled in most cases. You need to enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege in the code that uses that permission.
